# How pass a test about async method with Jest

Tags: typescript, testing, async-await, jestjs, nestjs

I try to write and run a test about an asynchronous method `doSomething` that return a `Promise<Foo[]>`. I use NestJS for a backend application.

Accoring to the Jest documentation it is possible and it seems to be quite easy.

I do

```
test('Test something', () => {
      const oldFoo = getFoo(); // type Foo[]
      const newFoo = getFoo();
      const expect = getFoo();

      return doSomething(newFoo, oldFoo).then((result) => {
        const cmp: boolean = helper.equal(expect, result);
        expect(cmp).toEqual(true);
      });
    }, 5000);
```

I tried too a simplier way to write that

```
test('Test something', async () => {
      const oldFoo = getFoo(); // type Foo[]
      const newFoo = getFoo();
      const expect = getFoo();

      const result = await doSomething(newFoo, oldFoo);

      expect(helper.equal(expect, result)).toEqual(true);
      });
    }, 5000);
```

I get back this error :

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout
```

I got the same error whatever the value of the timeout.

My question : is there any explanation other than the tested method is really too long ? Because out of the test (during runtime) the method is quite fast.

Can anyone help me to find the way to make it working ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with test code, besides mismatched brackets. A possible and likely explanation is that a promise is pending and will never resolve. The reason totally depends on your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are awaiting a promise, you might need to wrap your test asynchronously to allow the code to finish before examining the results.

For instance, in my End-to-End testing, I would do:

```
it('/api (POST) test to see data returned', async done => {

    const ResponseData = await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .post('/api')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json');

    expect(ResponseData.status).toBe(200);
    done();         // Call this to finish the test
});
```

I think in your test example then, you are just missing the done() callback function.

```
test('Test something', async done => {
    const oldFoo = getFoo(); // type Foo[]
    const newFoo = getFoo();
    const expect = getFoo();

    return doSomething(newFoo, oldFoo).then((result) => {
       const cmp: boolean = helper.equal(expect, result);
       expect(cmp).toEqual(true);
    });
    done();
 }
```